# back up windows 7 and my previous data of windows

Tags: windows-7, live-usb

I used LiveUSB to use ubuntu. Then I thought I wanted to use real ubuntu from USB because I thought the ubuntu from LiveUSB is just a test for ubuntu. So I installed ubuntu from Desktop icon on test ubuntu, thinking that any data of this installation would be burned into only my USB memory, not on my laptop itself.

But after installation, these data of ubuntu is burned into my laptop, and my previous data of windows 7 had gone.

Do you know haw to repair my previous windows data?

Answer (score 1):

No, I'm sorry.

You given Ubuntu the instructions to install to your HDD, and it has overwritten Windows, and all other data present on the HDD.

Comment: That's why we have back-ups...